# Prevent multiple submission on form submit (After validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue is form submitting multiple times on multiple click event. Also, submit button checks validation for input and then submitting all information. If someone clicked multiple times submit button after validation is done it submit data entry multiple so trying to prevent submit button on form submission.

```
  <form class="info" method="post" id="form1">
     <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>  



$(document).unbind('ready');
   $('.submitBtn').on('click', function(e){
       $('.submitBtn').addClass('disabled');
         console.log('clicked');
         var isValid = true;
         $('.email, .phone, #data').each(function(){
         var inputEl = $(this);
           if (inputEl.val() == ""){
             isValid = false;
             $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
           } else {
              // code action
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the submit button otherwise a user can submit with the keyboard also.

```js
$('form').on('submit', () => {
  $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<button onclick="console.log('click')" class="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```